# Web.config - read applicationSettings

Tags: c#, .net, web-config

I am using VS2015, C#.

I've created a couple of settings via project properties - settings. Some of them are saved here:

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="Calendar.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>


<applicationSettings>
    <Calendar.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="RedirectUriDEBUG" serializeAs="String">
        <value>https://localhost:44367/Login/RedirectGoogle</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="RedirectUriPRODUKCIJA" serializeAs="String">
        <value>https://ztest30.franjobrekalo.com/Login/RedirectGoogle</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LogPathDEBUG" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\Users\Frenky\Desktop\AdministrationLog.txt</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LogPathPRODUKCIJA" serializeAs="String">
        <value>h:\root\home\frenkyb-001\www\administration\AdministrationLog.txt</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LogPathTEST" serializeAs="String">
        <value>h:\root\home\frenkyb-001\www\testnotes\AdministrationLog.txt</value>
      </setting>
    </Calendar.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

ApplicationSettings section was generated by visual studio. Now I need to read from applicationSettings. I've tried numerous solutions, to my surprise, nothing worked. It seems that reading from appSettings is easy or from connectionStrings. Why is the problem with generated applicationSettings section?

**EDIT:**

Problem is with applicationSettings not with appSettings.

Comment: have you tried Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName ?

Comment: How exactly should I write this? I've tried with Properties.Settings.Default["LogPathDEBUG"]

Comment: is it helpful ? @System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"]

Comment: I think this is for appSettings not for applicationSettings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ConfigurationManager` class.

Try: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`. For detailed info check out [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**EDIT:** Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073914/get-value-from-web-config-applicationsettings-into-asp-net-markup?rq=1) once. It seems you cannot use inbuilt API's for ApplicationSettings. It only works for appSettings and connectionStrings. For your case you need to implement a custom class as explained in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the KEY 'RedirectUriDEBUG' in all your project code...
and Visual Studio will find a reference...

It should be somtething like

global::[YOUR_PACKAGE_NAMESPACE].Properties.Settings.Default.[YOUR_KEY]
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For me, The answer was in this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/four-ways-to-read-configuration-setting-in-c-sharp/

It shows how to use `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` method to get a `NameValueCollection` from `applicationSettings`

Example with custom section could be:

```
NameValueCollection PostSetting = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("BlogGroup/PostSetting") as NameValueCollection;
```

And with the default `ApplicationSettings` section:

```
NameValueCollection applicationSettings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ApplicationSettings") as NameValueCollection;
```